# computeOffset calendar program

Tags: c++, calendar

I have looked around and tried many things to get this to work. I am trying to build a calendar program. Everything seems to be working properly until i try to get the offset. I can run the program and it works when i put in 1 for the month number and 1753 for the year. However, any other year it does not return anything. Here is my code that I am using.

```
//Get number of days in the given year                                                                                                                                               
int numDaysInYear(int year)
{
   int dayStart;
   int numberFour = (year - 1) / 4;
   int oneHundred = (year - 1) / 100;
   int fourHundred = (year -1) / 400;

   dayStart = (year + numberFour - oneHundred + fourHundred) % 7;

   return dayStart;

}

//Compute the offset                                                                                                                                                                 
int computeOffset(int month, int year)
{
   int numDays = 0;
   int yearCount = year - 1753;

   for (int yearStart = 1753; yearStart > 1753; yearStart - 1 )
   {
      numDays = numDaysInYear(yearStart);

   }

   for (int monthCount = 1; monthCount > month; month++)
   {
      numDays = (numDaysInMonth(monthCount, year));
   }

   return numDays % 7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `year` is 2016.

```
//Get number of days in the given year                                                                                                                                               
int numDaysInYear(int year)
{
   int dayStart;
   int numberFour = (year - 1) / 4;
```

`numberFour` is 503.

```
   int oneHundred = (year - 1) / 100;
```

`oneHundred` is 201.

```
   int fourHundred = (year -1) / 400;
```

`fourHundred` is 5.

```
   dayStart = (year + numberFour - oneHundred + fourHundred) % 7;
```

This is (2016 + 503 - 201 + 5) mod 7, ie 2323 mod 7, which happens to be 6.

```
   return dayStart;
```

6 is not the number of days in the year.

```
}


int computeOffset(int month, int year)
{
   int numDays = 0;

   for (int yearCount = year - 1753; yearCount < year; year++){
      numDays = numDaysInYear(yearCount);
   }
```

This loop is not doing anything. It assigns to numDays, then overwrites it; the values are never used.

```
   for (int monthCount = 1; monthCount < month; month - 1)
   {
      numDays += numDaysInMonth(monthCount, year);
   }
```

Well, we don't know about your `numDaysInMonth` function. But `month - 1` is not changing the index variable: this will be an infinite loop unless `month` happens to be 1.

```
   return numDays % 7;
```

Why are you returning mod 7? That means the only possible values are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6.

```
}
```

Comment: Well it is a lot easier to walk through it when you separate it like this. Thank you for that. Once you said it is an infinite loop I saw my problem. The only problem I have now is in the function numDaysInYear. I need to revisit that function.